# R column matching

Tags: r, date

I have a set of dates (reference dates) and a data frame that enlists closing prices for some companies over a certain time period. i want to check if the data for all the companies is available corresponding to each date in the reference datelist. So, I would basically want to identify missing dates and insert them into the company data.

My data looks like this -

```
Company Code     Date              Closing Price                                  

ABB.NS          2010-08-09         288.12
ABB.NS          2010-08-10         289.2
ABB.NS          2010-08-12         302
.
.
.
ABB.NS          2010-08-30         278
ABAN.NS         2010-08-09         97.8
ABAN.NS         2010-08-10         98.6
.
.
.
ABAN.NS         2010-08-30        102.6
```

and my datelist includes all dates for the month 08/2010. So, my code should match the dates with the given dataset , identify the missing dates in all companies. (Here, for instance "2010-08-11" is missing for ABB) and insert a row for the missing data with the missing closing price as average of the prev and next closing price. So, here it will be (289.2+302)/2 .

I tried using the match function. But i was unable to integrate it for this exact purpose. Can someone help me out with this please?

Comment: I showed it for the 2 Companies you have in the example data.  The step `UnComp <- unique(df$Company.Code)` will get all the `Company names` and replicate it for the entire month in `df1`.  Just like I showed it.  In your description, you stated only for one month.  So, I am not sure what might be preventing you from applying this.

Comment: I got a bit confused. It works good. Thanks!

Comment: so, i tried it for a second datset and i got the following error: Error in approx(x[!na], y[!na], xout, ...) : need at least two non-NA values to interpolate In addition: Warning message: In is.na(y) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'

Comment: Could you show a small reproducible examplw that will get you the error

Comment: I split up the original dataset into two 500 and 400 companies each to make it smaller. While it worked on one, it didnt work on the other set. So, it basically has the exact same format as mentioned before

Comment: Check whether it works on a very small subset of the second dataset and if not, you can use `dput` and copy/paste that subset.  This might help in debugging the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
res <- merge(df,df1, by=c('Date', 'Company.Code'),all=TRUE)
library(zoo)
res$Closing.Price <- na.locf(na.approx(res$Closing.Price,
                                   na.rm=FALSE), na.rm=FALSE)

res1 <- res[with(res, order(Company.Code, Date)),]
row.names(res1) <- NULL
res1[41:43,]
#         Date Company.Code Closing.Price
#41 2010-08-10       ABB.NS         289.2
#42 2010-08-11       ABB.NS         295.6
#43 2010-08-12       ABB.NS         302.0
```

#### data

```
 df <- structure(list(Company.Code = c("ABB.NS", "ABB.NS", "ABB.NS", 
 "ABB.NS", "ABAN.NS", "ABAN.NS", "ABAN.NS"), Date = structure(c(14830, 
 14831, 14833, 14851, 14830, 14831, 14851), class = "Date"), Closing.Price =
 c(288.12, 289.2, 302, 278, 97.8, 98.6, 102.6)), .Names = c("Company.Code", 
 "Date", "Closing.Price"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")

 UnComp <- unique(df$Company.Code)
 df1 <- data.frame(Company.Code= rep(UnComp, each=31),
         Date=rep(seq(as.Date('2010-08-01'), by='1 day', 
            length.out=31),length(UnComp))
```